# How to dismiss view controller from react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

[Integration with exsiting apps doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html) 
shows how to present view controller whose content is react native .

```
RCTRootView *rootView =
  [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL: jsCodeLocation
                              moduleName: @"RNHighScores"
                       initialProperties:
                         @{
                           @"scores" : @[
                             @{
                               @"name" : @"Alex",
                               @"value": @"42"
                              },
                             @{
                               @"name" : @"Joel",
                               @"value": @"10"
                             }
                           ]
                         }
                           launchOptions: nil];
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
vc.view = rootView;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

What it doesn't tell you is how to dismiss the viewcontroller since we are in react native (javascript world) not objc/swift world anymore..

How can I call native `dimiss...` function on the viewcontroller?

Comment: You can read more in nativemodules https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html

Comment: @digit It would be much better if you give your solution along with resource here.

Answer (score 4):

Check this repo out: [tejasd/ios-playground](https://github.com/tejasd/ios-playground/commit/ba0a695563377771c6ca9121bb2136122ccc5a64)

Basic idea:

1.Import a native iOS class to React Native page, this iOS class does one thing: post a notification

```
let DismissViewControllerManager = NativeModules.DismissViewControllerManager;
```

2.Post a notification in React Native page

```
onButtonPress: () => {
                        DismissViewControllerManager.goBack();
                    }
```

3.Handle that notification in native iOS page and call `dismiss`

```
// add observer in viewDidLoad
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(goBack(_:)),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name("dismissViewController"),
                                               object: nil)

// remove observer in deinit (iOS 8 or earlier)
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)

// handle dismiss notification
func goBack(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```